# Нужна помощь с агрегированием данных в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Здравствуйте! Сразу привожу пример данных (JSON невалидный, не он важен):

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("57989a4eb9b56b535b29751d"),
   "subid":"adwords",
   "extrasubid":[  
      {  
         "subid":"ua",
         "_id":ObjectId("57989a566cb2296a5bc062fa"),
         "leadPrice":0,
         "revenue":0,
         "registrations":0,
         "hits":34
      },
      {  
         "subid":"ru",
         "_id":ObjectId("5798abcc4d31957714ca7736"),
         "uniques":0,
         "leadPrice":0,
         "revenue":0,
         "registrations":2,
         "hits":10
      }
   ],
   "__v":3
}{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5798a25e213c708b793ed04b"),
   "subid":"google",
   "extrasubid":[  
      {  
         "subid":"google",
         "_id":ObjectId("5798a282213c708b793ed04d"),
         "leadPrice":0,
         "revenue":0,
         "registrations":0,
         "hits":9
      }
   ],
   "__v":1
}
```

Так вот, в каждую коллекцию мне нужно добавить сумму `revenue`, `registrations`, `hits` из каждого объекта `extrasubid`, чтобы получилось примерно так:

```
{  
       "_id":ObjectId("57989a4eb9b56b535b29751d"),
       "subid":"adwords",
       "extrasubid":[  
          {  
             "subid":"ua",
             "_id":ObjectId("57989a566cb2296a5bc062fa"),
             "leadPrice":0,
             "revenue":0,
             "registrations":0,
             "hits":34
          },
          {  
             "subid":"ru",
             "_id":ObjectId("5798abcc4d31957714ca7736"),
             "uniques":0,
             "leadPrice":0,
             "revenue":0,
             "registrations":2,
             "hits":10
          },
       ],
       revenue: 0,
       registrations: 2,
       hits: 44,
       "__v":3
    }{  
       "_id":ObjectId("5798a25e213c708b793ed04b"),
       "subid":"google",
       "extrasubid":[  
          {  
             "subid":"google",
             "_id":ObjectId("5798a282213c708b793ed04d"),
             "leadPrice":0,
             "revenue":0,
             "registrations":0,
             "hits":9
          }
       ],
       revenue: 0,
       registrations: 2,
       hits: 9,
       "__v":1
    }
```

Как я это пытаюсь сделать:

```
Channel.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$extrasubid" },
    { $project: {
        _id: "$id",
        subid: "$subid",
        hits: { $sum: "$extrasubid.hits"},
        registrations: { $sum: "$extrasubid.registrations"},
        revenue: { $sum: "$extrasubid.revenue"},
        leadPrice: { $sum: "$extrasubid.leadPrice"},
        uniques: { $sum: "$extrasubid.uniques"}
    }},
], function (err, results) {
    console.log(results, results.length);
})
```

Но на выходе у меня получается 3 объекта, то есть все группируется по "extrasubid._id", а не просто "_id". Как это исправить и получить результат как выше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема устранена путем удаления `$unwind`. Код получился такой:

```
Channel.aggregate([
    { $project: {
        _id: "$id",
        subid: "$subid",
        hits: { $sum: "$extrasubid.hits"},
        registrations: { $sum: "$extrasubid.registrations"},
        revenue: { $sum: "$extrasubid.revenue"},
        leadPrice: { $sum: "$extrasubid.leadPrice"},
        uniques: { $sum: "$extrasubid.uniques"}
    }},
], function (err, results) {
    console.log(results, results.length);
})
```

Извините за неудобства.